Dafny array membership before and after permutation
After sorting an array, Dafny cannot verify an item in the old array exists in the sorted array. The sorted array is a permutation of the old array. What is missing here?
var a := new int[][100,2,3,4,5];
assert 4 == a[3];
assert 4 in a[..];
sort(a); // in-place array sort, ensures multiset(a[..]) == multiset(old(a[..]))
assert 4 in a[..]; //does not verify. Why?

Dafny knows the new array is sorted. But it does not every item from old array exists in the new array.

The issue boils down to triggers, which you can think of as facts that Dafny uses to recognize that other facts are true. The method discharges the fact that the multisets are equal before and after. Thus your assertions must lead through those triggers to get to information that you want.
var a := new int[][100,2,3,4,5];
assert 4 == a[3];
//assert 4 in a[..]; //optional now
assert 4 in multiset(a[..]); //trigger
sort(a);
assert 4 in a[..];

